# Read java special character from a string in a file

Tags: java, character

I am making a program that reads code from a java file and removes all the comments, but I am having some problems with special character since I am assuming everything inside the "  is part of a string

For example I have written in the file:

String my_string= " \" "

The string doesn't end when it reaches the second \, so how do I detect the \" as if it was a single character

Another issue I have is for when I have something like this

String my_string= ' " '

If I am reading the character one by one, how do I exactly I know I have reached an ' obviously something like this if(char==' ' ') doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if(char=='\'')`

And to detect escaped quotes, just put in a check for a backslash. If there is a backslash, do consider the next character to be a special character and not something to be parsed.

Comment: I am doing something like this if (strLine.charAt(x-1)!='\''&&strLine.charAt(x)='"') The problem is that this condition never checks